# How can I start page count from the beginning

Tags: numbering, titles, page-numbering

The thesis I wrote is a book class, the arabic page number start at the first page of the main content and before (TOC, Declaration, etc.) are roman numbers, also the title page is not numbered.

However, my university requires a different numbering. The number should start the be very beginning but the title page shall not have page number displayed. Can you tell me how can I set this up?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\title{Some Title}

\author{Name}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{pdfpages} % This allows insertion of pdf files. 
\setcounter{section}{0}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.46cm} 
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}  % Set the spacing between paragraphs

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{Chapter \thechapter. #1}{}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[RE]{\thepage}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{2mm}}
\graphicspath{{pictures/}}
\date{August 2015}
\begin{document}
\include{chapter1}
\bibliograph{bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How about `\setcounter{page}{2}`?

Comment: if you dont use `\frontmatter` `\mainmatter` it will be fine

Comment: Hi, touhami, The method has two problems for me. 1.) It doesn't start from the title page but the next page. 2) The chapter numbering so wrong. The introduction became chap4 before there are Abstract, Acknowledgement, Declaration .... before head.

Comment: @JiajunYang please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Answer (score 1):

I managed it:
1) I took Touhami's advice by removing frontmatter and mainmatter.

2) Put \addtocounter{page}{1} right after \maketitle. Allowing a page counter from 1 at the title page.

3) At first I had a problem that my Abstract became chapter 1. That was because I used \chapter instead of \chapter*.  Using \chapter* will suppress the chapter numbering.

If you have similar issue, hope this helps.